Extracting specific patterns of substrings from a material description column
I have a column named MAT_DESC in a table that contains material descriptions in a free-text format. Here are some sample values from the MAT_DESC column:

QWERTYUI PN-DR, Coarse, TR, 1-1/2 in, 50/Carton, 200 ea/Case, Dispenser Pack
2841 PC GREY AS/AF (20/CASE)
CI-1A, up to 35 kV, Compact/Solid, Stranded, 10/Case
MT53H7A4410WS5 WS WEREDSS PMR45678 ERTYUI HEERTYUIND 10/case
TYPE.2 86421-K40-F000, 1 Set/Pack, 100 Packs/Case
Clear, 1 in x 36 yd, 4.8 mil, 24 rolls per case




Material Desc
String to be Extracted




QWERTYUI PN-DR, Coarse, TR, 1-1/2 in, 50/Carton, 200 ea/Case, Dispenser Pack
50/Carton, 200 ea/Case


2841 PC GREY AS/AF (20/CASE)
20/CASE


TYPE.2 86421-K40-F000, 1 Set/Pack, 100 Packs/Case
1 Set/Pack, 100 Packs/Case


RTYU 31655, 240+, 6 in, 50 Discs/Roll, 6 Rolls/Case
50 Discs/Roll, 6 Rolls/Case


Clear, 1 in x 36 yd, 4.8 mil, 24 rolls per case
24 rolls per case


3M™ Victory Series™ Bracket MBT™ 017-873, .022, UL3, 0T/8A, Hk, 5/Pack
5/Pack


3M™ BX™ Dual Reader Protective Eyewear 11458-00000-20, Clear Anti-Fog Lens, Silver/Black Frame, +2.0 Top/Bottom Diopter, 20 ea/Case
20 ea/Case


4220VDS-QCSHC/900-000/A CABINET EMPTY
No units


3M™ Bumpon™ Protective Product SJ5476 Fluorescent Yellow, 3.000/Case
3.000/Case


3M™ Bumpon™ Protective Products SJ61A2 Black, 10,000/Case
10,000/Case



I'm trying to extract specific patterns of substrings from the MAT_DESC column, such as the quantity and unit information (e.g., "50 Discs/Roll", "200 ea/Case", "10/Case",50/Carton, 200 ea/Case etc.).
I'm currently using the following SQL query to attempt this:
SELECT MAT_DESC,
       CASE
         WHEN PATINDEX('%[A-Za-z]/[A-Za-z]%', MAT_DESC) > 0
         THEN CAST(PATINDEX('%[A-Za-z]/[A-Za-z]%', MAT_DESC) AS VARCHAR)
         ELSE 'No X'
       END AS Unit_Index
FROM TEMP_TABLE;

This query finds the pattern index of substrings like "Discs/Roll" or "ea/Case" using the PATINDEX function. Then, I planned to find the nearest comma indices before and after the pattern index and extract the substring using those indices.
However, this approach works for some scenarios but fails in others, especially when the material description contains additional information or is structured differently.
For python I use below regular expression to detect the pattern and retrieve substrings
pattern = r"(\d+)\s*(\w+)/(\w+)"

results = []

for desc in material_descriptions:
    matches = re.findall(pattern, desc)
    unit_strings = []
    if matches:
        for match in matches:
            quantity, unit1, unit2 = match
            unit_string = f"{quantity} {unit1}/{unit2}"
            unit_strings.append(unit_string)
    if unit_strings:
        unit_info = ", ".join(unit_strings)
        results.append((desc, unit_info))

for material_desc, unit_info in results:
    print(f"Material Description: {material_desc}")
    print(f"Unit Information: {unit_info}")
    print()

Python script fails in the below listed scenarios



Material Desc
String to be Extracted




3M™ Victory Series™ Bracket MBT™ 017-873, .022, UL3, 0T/8A, Hk, 5/Pack
5/Pack


3M™ BX™ Dual Reader Protective Eyewear 11458-00000-20, Clear Anti-Fog Lens, Silver/Black Frame, +2.0 Top/Bottom Diopter, 20 ea/Case
20 ea/Case


4220VDS-QCSHC/900-000/A CABINET EMPTY
No units


3M™ Bumpon™ Protective Product SJ5476 Fluorescent Yellow, 3.000/Case
3.000/Case


3M™ Bumpon™ Protective Products SJ61A2 Black, 10,000/Case
10,000/Case



Is there a more robust way to extract specific patterns of substrings (like quantity and unit information) from a free-text material description column? I'm open to solutions in SQL and Python

The more robust way is to store it properly structured in the first place. If you have no say on that, then extracting data is much easier done in your application than in SQL, since SQL has no regular expressions.

If you wish to proceed with this approach, please show us the examples which fail.

Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I don't have control over how this data is structured - the material descriptions come to us in this free-text format, and we need to work with what we have.
The sample values I provided all fail with my current approach due to issues like missing commas around the quantities, multiple units listed

Even if the data comes to you this, can you not preprocess it before inserting it into your database?

And if multiple units are listed, how do you want to handle that?

No, I can't preprocess the data before it gets inserted into the database - I have to work with it as is. And if multiple units are listed, the ideal solution would be to extract both the unit strings.

So please update your question and show the exact output your desire from the provided input.

Although the actual answer to your question "Is there a more robust way to extract specific patterns of substrings" is "No" but I expect you really want help to accomplish the listed goal.

You should provide expected output from that string in a table form together with the sample row

@rohi that's much better!

It is a painful exercise, especially in SQL Server.
Broadly my suggestions:
1 Try to parse data into useful chunks e.g.
SELECT *
FROM TEMP_TABLE
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT( MAT_DESC, ',' ) AS Chunks( chunk )

2 Identify useful pieces e.g.
SELECT *
FROM TEMP_TABLE
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT( MAT_DESC, ',' ) AS Chunks( chunk )
WHERE chunk LIKE '%Discs/Roll%' OR chunk LIKE '%ea/Case%' OR etc .....

You will have to specify a "whitelist" of strings to keep.
Instead of "whitelisting" you can try putting your PATINDEX query (PATINDEX('%[A-Za-z]/[A-Za-z]%', chunk) > 0) in the WHERE clause but based on your data it will likely return some false positives which you will need to explicitly exclude e.g.
SELECT *
FROM TEMP_TABLE
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT( MAT_DESC, ',' ) AS Chunks( chunk )
WHERE PATINDEX('%[A-Za-z]/[A-Za-z]%', chunk) > 0 AND NOT chunk LIKE '%AS/AF%'

